# How to get list of connected users?

Tags: ably-realtime

I have many channels, and I need to get statistic, how many users connecter to every channel and their identity.

How can I get a list of connected users to every channel?

Answer (score 0):

An Ably Engineer here,
You can get a list of each user either by tracking them using presence, or using the [meta]channel API.

Metachannels stream things like connection events and channel status changes to your server or anything else.
The documentation is here: https://ably.com/documentation/realtime/metachannels